# material ui v 1.0.0 DropDownMenu

Tags: drop-down-menu, material-ui, beta

I have a problem with the 1.0.0 (beta) version of material-ui. There is no DropDownMenu. Ist the dropdown menu realy completely removed, or it just have another name? I found nothing in the documentations and via google ...

With best regards
Tony

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the Menu component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Material UI v1 they are called [Selects](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/selects/).